# Как добавить в layout Label, если он был создан в .kv файле?

Tags: python, kivy

Мне нужно добавить Label в AnchorLayout. Как это сделать в .kv файле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Root>:
    AnchorLayout:
        id: anchorLayout
```

В коде получаешь объект AnchorLayout по ids корневого виджета, где у тебя находится AnchorLayout:

```
class Root(BoxLayout):
    def addLabelInAnchorLayout(self):
        self.ids.anchorLayout.add_widget(Label())
```